# Efficient way of Square of a Sorted Array

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I am solving leetcode problem [977. Squares of a Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/squares-of-a-sorted-array/)
, reading

> Given an integer array `nums` sorted in **non-decreasing order**, return *an array of the squares of each number sorted in non-decreasing order*.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> > **Input:** nums = [-4,-1,0,3,10]
> > **Output:** [0,1,9,16,100]
> > **Explanation:** After squaring, the array becomes [16,1,0,9,100].
> > After sorting, it becomes [0,1,9,16,100].
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> > **Input:** nums = [-7,-3,2,3,11]
> > **Output:** [4,9,9,49,121]

I solved this through `map()` and then use `sorted()` for sorting purpose and lastly converted in `toIntArray()`.

My solution

```
class Solution {
    fun sortedSquares(nums: IntArray): IntArray {
     return nums.map { it * it }.sorted().toIntArray()
    }
}
```

After all I am taking a look in the discuss success, I found this **[solution](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/fun-with-arrays/521/introduction/3240/discuss/557344/Kotlin-O(n)-95-time-100-space)**

```
class Solution {
    fun sortedSquares(A: IntArray): IntArray {
        
        // Create markers to use to navigate inward since we know that
        // the polar ends are (possibly, but not always) the largest
        var leftMarker = 0
        var rightMarker = A.size - 1
        
        // Create a marker to track insertions into the new array
        var resultIndex = A.size - 1
        val result = IntArray(A.size)
        
        // Iterate over the items until the markers reach each other.
        // Its likely a little faster to consider the case where the left
        // marker is no longer producing elements that are less than zero.
        while (leftMarker <= rightMarker) {
            // Grab the absolute values of the elements at the respective
            // markers so they can be compared and inserted into the right
            // index.
            val left = Math.abs(A[leftMarker])
            val right = Math.abs(A[rightMarker])
            
            // Do checks to decide which item to insert next.
            result[resultIndex] = if (right > left) {
                rightMarker--
                right * right
            } else {
                leftMarker++
                left * left
            }
            
            // Once the item is inserted we can update the index we want
            // to insert at next.
            resultIndex--
        }
        
        return result
    }
}
```

The guy also mention in the title `Kotlin -- O(n), 95% time, 100% space`

So my solution is equal in time and space complexity with other solution with efficient time and space? Or Is there any better solution?

Comment: You might find the Big-O Cheat Sheet a useful aid - I certainly do https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my solution is equal in time and space complexity with other solution with efficient time and space?

No, your solution runs in `O(n log n)` time, as it relies on `sorted()`, which likely runs in `O(n log n)`. Since the alternative solution does not sort the items, it indeed runs on `O(n)` time. Both solutions use `O(n)` space, although your solution uses three times as much space (each of `map`, `sorted` and `toIntArray` create a copy of the input).

Comment: the second solution which I mention is better ?

Comment: Also can you please explain me how my solution is taking `0( n log n )` ? Can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: What additional explanation do you need? As @Egor said, best sorting algorithms are `n * log(n)` by average. You use sorting, so your solution can't be better than that. The other solution you provide doesn't have to sort results, because it produces the data in already sorted order. As a result, it has better time complexity.

Comment: @vivekmodi I've noticed you posting a lot of questions where you say you want the *fastest* or *most efficient and elegant* algorithm. If that's something you genuinely want to aim for, you'll need to study algorithms and how to analyse their time and memory requirements, so you can look at code like this and understand what it's doing and how that impacts things, and use those approaches and avoid issues in your own code. If you just want "the best code" then that always depends on the situation. I'd rather read your solution than that efficient one - but it depends if the efficiency matters

Comment: `the second solution which I mention is better ?` - please define "better". In terms of raw performance - it is better, in terms of readability and simplicity - I would argue your original solution is better. You rarely want the absolute fastest solution, in many cases the simplest solution is the best one.

Comment: @cactustictacs yes I asked a lot of questions regarding fastest solution and efficient. I am learning data structure and algorithms that's why I asked questions. I always tried first myself and then asked which one is good for comparison. I am facing difficulties to analyse the complexity that' why I asked you guys to help me. Do you know any tutorial why explain all of these how to analyse stuff ? I am trying to learn leetcode to solve complex problem but there they will not explain the complexity stuff.. thanks for your always help me. I really appreciate you guys

Comment: @vivekmodi I don't really have any recommendations, if I were you I'd look for an academic course or a book that people say they found helpful. But this site looks pretty good: https://discrete.gr/complexity/ There's a lot of explanation of basic stuff at the beginning, but it's showing you how to approach this stuff from a fundamental level, so you can identify what's happening in any algorithm you come across. It's about working out exactly what's going on, and how the size of the data you're working with affects that. It's a skill you have to develop really, like solving puzzles

Comment: I recall watching the [Algorithms](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1) course on Coursera a while ago, I really enjoyed it & can highly recommend. Part 1 teaches algorithm analysis theory, and introduces various sorting algorithms. IIRC it also includes the formal proof that no generic sorting algorithm can get faster than O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int[] sortedSquares(int[] nums) {
        int n = nums.length;
        int[] squared= new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            squared[i]=nums[i]*nums[i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(squared);
     return squared;   
    }
}
```

Comment: This answers neither of the explicit questions. While the procedure shown may be effective, it is in*efficient* by comparison.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**